# ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated in prolog

Tags: prolog, instantiation-error

I'm new user in Prolog, I am trying to scale and transform coordinates in maps but got error "not sufficiently instantiated " on **scale and transform RULE**. here is my rules, it seems that the Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated , could you please give me solution how we can fix this issue. it seam the problem is in scale and transform rule where I use "IS" operator

```
transform_all :-
   forall(
      representation(Id, Geom),
      (  transform(Geom, TGeom),
         record_transformed_rep(Id, TGeom)
      )
   ).
transform_all :-
    forall(
       (  representation(Id, Geom),
          not(transformed_rep(Id))
       ),
       (  transform(Geom, TGeom),
          record_transformed_rep(Id, TGeom)
       )
    ).

%transformation
transform(Geom, TGeom) :-
   scale(Geom, value(10000), SGeom),
   translate(SGeom, value(-7.5, -51.9), TGeom).

%record_the_transformed_geometries
record_transformed_rep(Id, TGeom) :-
   retractall(representation(Id, _)),
   assert(representation(Id, TGeom)),
   assert(transformed_rep(Id)).  %% flag to avoid infinite loop

%scale_and_translate_metric_Map
scale(point(X,Y), value(V), point(Sx,Sy)) :-
   Sx is X * V,
   Sy is Y * V.

scale(polyline([]), value(_), polyline([])).
scale(polyline([P|R]), value(V), polyline([Sp|Sr])) :-
   scale(P,value(V),Sp),
   scale(polyline(R), value(V), polyline(Sr)).

%translate_coordinate_of_metric_map
translate(point(X,Y), value(Dx,Dy), point(Sx,Sy)) :-
   Sx is X + Dx,
   Sy is Y + Dy.

translate(polyline([]), value(_,_), polyline([])).
translate(polyline([P|R]), value(Dx,Dy), polyline([Sp|Sr])) :-
   translate(P,value(Dx,Dy),Sp),
   translate(polyline(R), value(Dx,Dy), polyline(Sr)).
```

Comment: This question has been asked many times, and the answer is always: you are trying to add free variables instead of numbers. Check your code carefully and make sure you give `is` numbers.

Comment: Please provide a definition (e.g., a list of facts) for `representation/2`!